# Php sql timestamp for Iphone app

Tags: php, iphone, sql, timestamp

how can i do it  just like Twitter and Facebook does.

- If post was made within 1 hour - show how many minutes ago.  (ie: 5 minutes ago, 39 minutes ago, etc.)
- If post was made more than 1 hour ago, but less than 24 hours ago, show how many hours (ie: 2 hours 
  ago, 7 hours ago, 22 hours ago)
- If post was made more than 24 hours ago, show how many days ago post was made (3 days ago, 8 
  days ago, 18 days ago, etc.)

how can i do it using php and sql ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use `DateTime:diff()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Compare time(), which is current, to the database date.